# integrating over a geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose $\mathcal{M}$ is a Riemannian manifold with the volume measure $d\mu$(induced by the Riemannian metric ) and $\gamma$ is a geodesic on $M$. Is it true that $$\int_{\gamma}fd\nu\leq\int _{\mathcal{M}}fd\mu,$$
if yes what replaces $d\nu$ exactly?
Edit:

$$\int_{\gamma}fd\nu\int _{\mathcal{M}}d\mu\leq\int _{\mathcal{M}}fd\mu\int_{\gamma}d\nu,$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is $d\nu$? Do you mean the measure induced by the induced metric on $\gamma$ as a submanifold? In that case the answer is **no**.

Let $\mathcal{M} = S^1\times S^1$ with coordinates $(x,y)\in [0,2\pi)^2$, with the line element $ds^2 = dx^2 + \epsilon dy^2$. And let $\gamma$ be the geodesic $y = 0$. The induced Riemannian metric on the geodesic is $d\ell^2 = dx^2$.

Let $f = 1$ the constant function. Then $\int_\gamma f d\nu = 2\pi$, while $\int_{\mathcal{M}}fd\mu = 4\pi^2 \epsilon$. By choosing $\epsilon$ sufficiently small you invalidate the proposed inequality.

---

More generally, purely by dimensional considerations you see that it is unreasonable to expect any expressions of the form you wrote to hold, except possibly in the case that $\gamma$ is treated as a (measure zero) subset of $\mathcal{M}$, and $d\nu$ is the measure $d\mu$, and $f$ is non-negative. Then the LHS is trivially zero and the RHS is non-negative.

Comment: @ Willie Wong I changed the inequality.

Comment: Edit is still false. Let $M$ be the manifold given by the disjoint union of what I wrote in my above example, and $\mathbb{S}^2_r$, the standard sphere of radius $r$. Let $f = 0$ on the sphere. Now take $r\to\infty$. The LHS blows up, the RHS remains the fixed.

Comment: If you want a connected manifold, you can consider the case where $f$ has compact support in a small tubular neighborhood of the geodesic.